# Is there a way to pause an Animated .PNG (APNG) on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, png, apng

I'd like to support APNG files, but with hover to animate functionality on some pages so it's not too overwhelming.

I'd rather not have to store both an animated and still version of the user profile picture to do so and instead just pause the animated .png files on the first frame.

I was hoping it'd be possible with Javascript/jQuery but I've not found anything referencing this at all and barely anything on how to handle Animated PNG files.

Comment: There's not a built in way to do it. You'd have to break up the APNG into its frames and manually play and pause the frames.